# How to make differential backup in linux?

Tags: linux

I have to write a script to take differential backup (of a directory).  Differential backup:

> A differential backup backs up only the files that changed since the last full back. For example, suppose you do a full backup on Sunday. On Monday you back up only the files that changed since Sunday, on Tuesday you back up only the files that changed since Sunday, and so on until the next full backup.

Suppose for Example:

Monday - Performed a full backup and save the file set.

Thursday - Want to Perform a differential backup using the same file set. All files
          that have changed since the full backup are backed up in the
          differential backup.

From now on, if I require I will use the script so please suggest to proceed or how to write the script to automate this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not *quite* what you asked for, but very similar in effect (i.e., you "pay" storage only for files that actually have changed):

Using rsync, creating hard links for unchanged files.

The big advantage is that each "snapshot" is a full-fledged backup in its own right, i.e. on recovery you only have to restore that one snapshot (instead of recovering a base and its increments).

There is good documentation on that approach available at [www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/](http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/)

Comment: This seem to be a very favorable option, until you look into the caveats of rsync. Doesn't seem the masters have even mastered it. (re: mikerubel's writeup contains many warnings, version conflictions of handling, and uncertain outcomes)

Comment: @AlexSummers: You shouldn't judge the appropriateness of a solution in 2017 by a writeup last modified in 2004. I linked to that writeup as it was the one I could locate ad-hoc when I wrote the answer all those years ago...

Comment: Oh well there's that :) I surely didn't downvote it. I should have looked at the date, what a necro I am. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

> **Duplicity** backs [up] directories by producing encrypted tar-format volumes and uploading them to a remote or local file server. Because duplicity uses librsync, the incremental archives are space efficient and only record the parts of files that have changed since the last backup. Because duplicity uses GnuPG to encrypt and/or sign these archives, they will be safe from spying and/or modification by the server.

http://duplicity.nongnu.org/

Duplicity implements a traditional backup scheme, where the initial archive contains all information (full backup) and in the future only the changed information is added. However, here are some advantages it may have over other similar solutions:

- Easy to use: Although duplicity is a command-line utility, the semantics are relative simply. To take a basic example, this command backs up the /usr directory to the remost host host.net via scp: `duplicity /usr scp://host.net/target_dir`
- Encrypted and signed archives: The archives that duplicity produces can be encrypted and signed using GnuPG, the standard for free software cryptology. The remote location will not be able to infer much about the backups other than their size and when they are uploaded. Also, if the archives are modified on the remote side, this will be detected when restoring.
- Bandwidth and space efficient: Duplicity uses the rsync algorithm so only the changed parts of files are sent to the archive when doing an incremental backup. For instance, if a long log file increases by just a few lines of text, a small diff will be sent to and saved in the archive. Other backup programs may save a complete copy of the file.
- Standard file format: Although archive data will be encrypted, inside it is in standard GNU-tar format archives. A full backup contains normal tarballs, and incremental backups are tar archives of new files and the deltas from previous backups. The deltas are in the format produced by librsync's command-line utility rdiff. Although you should never have to look at a duplicity archive manually, if the need should arise they can be produced and processed using GnuPG, rdiff, and tar.
- Choice of remote protocol: Duplicity does not make many demands on its archive server. As long as files can be saved to, read from, listed, and deleted from a location, that location can be used as a duplicity backend. Besides increasing choice for the user, it can make a server more secure, as clients only require minimal access.

Currently local file storage, scp/ssh, ftp, rsync, HSI, WebDAV, Tahoe-LAFS, and Amazon S3 are supported, and others shouldn't be difficult to add.

Comment: For sure it supports incremental backup but not (yet) differential !

Comment: My mistake :) I'll leave my answer though if anyone's not bothered about differential/incremental and is just looking for a working backup solution that doesn't require full backups.

Comment: Right... but for my own personal backups, I really prefer differential. So I just have to implement it in duplicity...

Answer (score 1):

`man dump`

```
 -level#
              The dump level (any integer). A level 0, full backup, guarantees
              the  entire  file  system  is copied (but see also the -h option
              below). A level number above 0, incremental backup,  tells  dump
              to copy all files new or modified since the last dump of a lower
              level. The default level is 0. Historically only levels 0  to  9
              were  usable  in  dump,  this  version is able to understand any
              integer as a dump level.
```

It is worth reading about the "Tower of Hanoi" incremental backup scheme and understanding why and how that is used.

See also http://surf.ml.seikei.ac.jp/~nakano/dump-restore/dump-restore-mini-HOWTO.en.html#ss3.3

And http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_backup which says

> A Unix example would be:
>
> `rsync -e ssh -va --link-dest=$dst/hourly.1 $remoteserver:$remotepath $dst/hourly.0`
>
> The use of rsync's `--link-dest` option is what makes this
>   command an example of incremental backup.

Comment: Is this standard on linux systems or does it need to be installed? What filesystems does it work with?

Comment: On AIX at least, `dump` refers to something completely different...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - It was on my Centos 5.7 Linux system. It's been on every Unix system I recall using. I *suspect* it is on most desktop and server oriented Linux systems but probably not on Linux distros aimed at appliances or small devices (e.g. Android, Washing machines, routers). My CentOS manpage mentions ext2/ext3 (ext3 is what 5.7 uses by default).

Comment: You might also look at http://dump.sourceforge.net/isdumpdeprecated.html for further pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write script when tools exist that do just this.

SVN, GIT

You can setup svn and commit your directory. Every time you commit you save difference. Save = Backup in this case.

You can go back in time and restore snapshots of previous commits.

This solution is [discussed at length here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61888/using-subversion-for-general-purpose-backup)

Comment: @ChrisF He asked for differential backup, SVN is tool just for that isn't it?

Comment: You didn't explain that in your answer - you do now so it's a better answer.

Comment: @ChrisF sorry you are right, sometimes I'm not very clear with my thoughts :)

Comment: You are aware of the hideous storage requirements of this "solution"? "*If a hammer is your only tool, every problem starts looking like a nail...*"

Comment: @DevSolar I disagree, it saves difference so no "hideous storage requirements".

Comment: @DevSolar That quote is uncalled for, though I like it allot.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze: At the very minimum, with SVN you have *three* copies of each file: The file, the copy of the file in the repository, and the copy of the file in the .svn subfolder (at least doubling the space requirements of whatever you want to keep backed up, *at its current location*). And unless you take additional administrative action, all historic versions of all files are kept in the repo, [including the corresponding logs](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#bdblogs). There are other issues, but it should suffice to realize what a VCS is meant for, and what it is not meant for.

Comment: not to forget all this stuff is uncompressed - which might be an issue at least with huge text files (instead of a compression factor upt to 1:10 you have at least 3 full copies)

Comment: @DevSolar What about ease of use? ease of restore? ability to visualize changes? easy to add files? detailed tracking?

Comment: Discussed here in detail actually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61888/using-subversion-for-general-purpose-backup

Comment: @Izzy and DevSolar you are both right. I will not delete my answer though, as it is an option.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze I didn't argue that. Just thought you might want to add those facts to your answer (they might get "lost" to the reader here in the comments).

Comment: While using git directly might not be a good idea, its underlying principle can be used very nicely for the purpose. See [bup](https://github.com/bup/bup) - _Highly efficient file backup system based on the git packfile format_.

Answer (score 0):

I use Butterfly Backup (https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/Butterfly-Backup). I organize all the backups in a simple catalog and I can interact directly with the file system without switching to anything else. It also offers a restore and export option.

Simple differential backup command:

$ bb backup --computer mypc --destination /backup --data User Config --type Unix --mode Differential